# operations with sets in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have seminar paper where I have to find some of the operations with sets in Prolog, for example for subset:

```
subset([],V).
subset([H|T1],[H|T2]):-subset(T1,T2).
subset([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- lt(H2,H1),subset([H1|T1],T2).
```

I have trouble with finding some of them so I would be very thankful if anyone writes them down:

- check if element is a member of set
- check if set is empty, number of el
  in the set
- check if all el of the set are
  numbers
- check if two sets are the same

Answer (score 2):

Check out the section [library(lists): List Manipulation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29) in the SWI-Prolog manual. Try out the set-specific predicates listed there and check their source code using `listing/1`, e.g.

```
?- listing(subset).
lists:subset([], _) :- !.
lists:subset([A|C], B) :-
    memberchk(A, B),
    subset(C, B).
```

Sets are represented as lists, so to check for members use `member/2`, to check if a set is empty, check if it unifies with an empty list. To check the nature of the elements of the set, e.g. to see if all are numbers, you can use `maplist`:

```
?- maplist(number, [1, -1.2, 0]).
true.
```

Two sets are equivalent if they are subsets of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, set is usually represented by list. So your first listed operation is the `member/2` predicate on list, the second is simply checking the set is empty list or not. Some important set-theoretic operations are:

- **union** of set A and set B: giving a set containing elements either in A or in B.
- **intersection** of A and B: giving a set containing elements both in A and in B.
- **difference** of A and B: giving a set containing elements in A and not in B.

Some of those operations are standard operations, for example, description of `union/3` and `intersection/3` are in Kaarel's link. Some nice discussion about set operations and their implementation  in Prolog could be found here: http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/sets.html.